Algebra Isomorphism and embedding between matrix algebra and tensor products of algebras
Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote real numbers. For which $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $A$ are $Mat_n(\mathbb{R} \otimes A)$ and $Mat_n(\mathbb{R}) \otimes A$ algebra isomorphic?
If $A$ is finite dimensional with dimension $d$, what is the smallest number $m$ that we can have an algebra embedding from $Mat_n(A)$ onto $Mat_m(\mathbb{R})$?
For example what if $A$ is a finite-dimensional division $\mathbb{R}$-algebra?


They are always isomorphic. 2. $M_n(A)$ always acts faithfully on $A^n$, so at worst you can take $m = n \dim A$, and this bound is sharp for division algebras.

